# How to debug kernel driver using gdb and vmlinux

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

We are using zynq 7020 SoC in our custom card. also I am using petalinux V2020.1.

I have developed a custom driver and my driver will be loaded during the kernel boot.

But after that my driver hangs at some point and i am not able to boot the board completely.

So i need to debug my driver using gdb and vmlinux. I think i need to stop at uboot and run vmlinux.

Could somebody help me to use gdb to debug my kernel driver hang issue.

Comment: "*my driver will be loaded during the kernel boot*" -- Suggest that you not conflate "loading" a module (which could also be a driver) with "initializing" a driver.  Rather than gdb, why not use printk()s to narrow down where the problem is?

Comment: @sawdust, `gdb`, but more precisely `kgdb` is much better than `printk()`s, esp. when you have no possibility / time to recompile everything.